# I'm using angularJs and Using ng-if in nested ng-repeat. How to do variable comparison in ng-if?

Tags: angularjs

```
<tbody ng-repeat="obj1 in personalProfileCtrl.workArray">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-llyw">{{obj1.role}}</td>
    <td class="tg-llyw">{{obj1.name}}</td>
    <td class="tg-llyw" colspan="2">
           {{obj1.start_date}} -{{obj1.end_date}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in personalProfileCtrl.workAchievementsArray" 
     ng-if="obj2.place=='{obj1.name}'">
     <td class="tg-0pkys">{{obj2.title}}</td>
     <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="6">
       {{obj2.achievements_description}}
     </td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>
```

This line of code is not working `ng-if="obj2.place=='{obj1.name}'"`

Here profileCtrl is controller

1. workAchievement is array of object
2. workArray is also a array of object

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to add the extra `'{}'` to the `obj1.name`, so `ng-if="obj2.place==obj1.name"` should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in personalProfileCtrl.workAchievementsArray" 
      ̶n̶g̶-̶i̶f̶=̶"̶o̶b̶j̶2̶.̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶=̶=̶'̶{̶o̶b̶j̶1̶.̶n̶a̶m̶e̶}̶'̶"̶
      ng-if="obj2.place == obj1.name">
     <td class="tg-0pkys">{{obj2.title}}</td>
     <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="6">
       {{obj2.achievements_description}}
     </td>
  </tr>
```